# Why is the button I created in Interface Builder not displayed?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I created a button in interface builder.  I defined an IBOutlet and an IBAction in the header file.  I implemented the IBAction method in the .m.  I made the connection from file owner to the button and from the button to the file owner.

The problem is that when I run the app in the simulator, I don't see it.  I hid the other main item in the view to be extra sure that there's nothing on top of it. I'm copying the approach I used successfully to add buttons to other views but for some reason, I just don't see anything.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple and I would be grateful if some one could tell me what it is.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Go into IB and tell me what your object hierarchy looks like (the panel on the left side).

Comment: The skinny column to the immediate left of my IB view shows the hollow yellow box for the file owner and the solid orange box for the first responder.  Then there's a solid line beneath that and a grey square with a white dashed line box with a little dot beside it that pops up the tag 'View' when I hover over it.  To the left of that, when I click on the second top bar icon and highlight the hierarchical option, I see a flat list of about 20 classes that are part of my app.  I hope that's what you were asking for.

Comment: It is.  Your button, is it inside the view's list when you click the triangle?  If it isn't, then it won't be displayed.

Comment: I don't think so.  When I click on the view, it pops up a little black rectangle with the word View but there's nothing list under it.  Do I need to connect the button to the view?

Comment: No, not connect it, make it a subview.  Drag your button over the 'view' row until it lights up with a blue box.  then release.  it will place your button under the 'view' row and indent it slightly to the right.

Comment: Wait now I get it, I clicked on the little triangle in the bottom left and it showed a better object hierarchy.  So yes, it's view and then under that two buttons in the view, one of which is not displayed.  The other one is incidentally.

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for the tip about making sure the button is a subView but I don't think that's causing the problem.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your button isn't in the view hierarchy.  Are you absolutely sure your interface builder box looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I took a screenshot but I don't know how to include it in this message but yes, that's what it looks like.  I don't see the icon, maybe I don't have enough reputation?

Comment: Edit your question then click the little image icon above the text box.  it'll guide you through uploading an image.

Comment: Sorry CodaFi, I can't add the image because I don't have enough reputation points.